# githubからダウンロードしたサンプルアプリとワトソンAssistantをデプロイするとタイムアウトとなる

Tags: github, デプロイ, watson-api

ワトソンAssistantを利用してチャットボットを作成しています。
githubからダウンロードしたアプリとIBM Cloudをcf pushでデプロイすると、タイムアウトとなってしまいます。
２月に試した時はデプロイできたのですが、先日、cf pushでデプロイを試みたらタイムアウトとなってしまいました。
（URL)
https://github.com/methodist/conversation-simple-for-TanakaSPECIAL

IBMテクニカルセンターにサポートチケットを利用して聞いてみると、IBM Cloud側に問題はなく、アプリのコードに何か問題があるとの回答がきました。

原因等わかる方、もしくは、コード等を修正頂けると大変助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: リンクなさっているコードはご自身のチームで作ってらっしゃるものでしょうか？

Comment: forkしたリポジトリのようで、2月にいくつかのコミットがありますね。1月初旬のコミットでデプロイするとどうなるのでしょうか。

Comment: >nekketsuuuさん　GitHubからダウンロードしたアプリは、自身で作っているものではないです。Watson Conversationとデプロイするためのこのアプリを教えてもらいました。教えてくれた人からも、タイムアウトとなる原因はわからないといわれてしまいました。。。

Comment: >cubickさん　３月の初旬に、当該ファイルをダウンロードし、デプロイした時には、成功しました。同じファイルを使って、６月初旬にデプロイを試みたら、タイムアウトとなってしまいました。